# How to open file with gz extendion in spyder?

Tags: python, gzip

I have got a file whith `gz` extension. Basically it was just a python file with `py` extension. After some manipulaition with that file It bacome file with `gz` ext. How to get it back?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1):

You did one of two things.

1. You compressed the file using a command like zip, winzip, gzip etc
2. You renamed the file with .gz as the extension

A file extension is just an indicator of the expected file contents.  I can have a text file with python code and a gz extension.

To fix your problem, open the file in a text editor.  If the contents look like garbage, you've opened a compressed file and will need to uncompressed it using   appropriate software.

Most likely, you will find that the file contains readable python code.  In that case simply save the file with the correct extension.

An pay closer attention to how you are manipulating your files in the future.